# seq() with multiple increments

Tags: r, seq

I'd like to create a sequence with three different increements. From 6 to 15 for example an increment of 0.7 . The folowing sequence should start with the last number of previous sequence (in this case 14.4).
By this I want to model the diameter increment of a tree dependant on the diameter-class (small 6-14.99; medium 15 - 29.99; big >30).

```
    dbh <- c(seq(from = 6, to = 15, by = temp$DBH_growth[temp$dbh_class == "sma"]),
     seq(from = 15, to = 30, by = temp$DBH_growth[temp$dbh_class == "med"]),
     seq(from = 30, to = 300, by = temp$DBH_growth[temp$dbh_class == "big"]))
```

Like this code, but starting with the last number of the sequence before.

Comment: Hi @fritz, welcome to SO! For better reproducibility make sure to provide some sample data for others to be able to help you out (the data frame `temp` and thus the increments are unknown).

Answer (score 0):

Something like this

```
sma <- seq(6, 15, .7)
med <- seq(max(sma), 30, 1)
lar <- seq(max(med), 300, 1.4)
dbh <- c(sma, med, lar)
```

supposing that `.7,1,1.4` are the increments for small, medium, large respectively, or in your case

```
sma <- seq(6, 15, temp$DBH_growth[temp$dbh_class == "sma"])
med <- seq(max(sma), 30, temp$DBH_growth[temp$dbh_class == "med"])
lar <- seq(max(med), 300, temp$DBH_growth[temp$dbh_class == "big"])

dbh <- c(sma, med, lar)
```